# Fragments, viewpagers, Async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I have a view pager holding 3 fragments each fragment contains an async task that loads different urls for json data that is loaded into a custom listview in each fragment.

may problem is the view pager loads two fragments at a time, this delays the loding process, the progress dialogs from the next fragment are loaded in the current fragment. 
how can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Dont load the three pages simulatneouly when the fragment is selected load the page.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if(this.isVisible()){
        if (!isVisibleToUser) {
        // TODO your async task .
        }

    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

Comment: when used in my fragment classes they the async task is not executed at all

Comment: Is your AsyncTask a inner class. If yes try to created a separate class and then call it

Comment: whats the significance for that

Answer (score 0):

set setOffscreenPageLimit for View Pager

```
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

where mPager is object of ViewPager.Hope this will help